# Force wix installer to specific language

Tags: localization, wix, installation, windows-installer

I've created a Wix msi installer with German, English, Chinese and Japanese languages support.
How can I install a English version at Chinese OS?

Comment: The question has been resolved.

Comment: msiexec /I xxx.msi ProductLanguage=9

Comment: Consider posting a proper answer to this question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If your mult-language installer is xxx.msi. You can use the command below to force the installer install English version:

```
msiexec /I xxx.msi ProductLanguage=9
```